# $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\geq|\operatorname{rank}(A)-\operatorname{rank}(B)|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Question:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9kwR.jpg)

Solution: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBMd.jpg)

$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\geq|\operatorname{rank}(A)-\operatorname{rank}(B)|$

I have recently started learning linear algebra, although I have solved some rank problems and have seen some inequalities involving rank of a matrix but I dont know what is this inequality, I have not seen this before, a quick google search also doesnot help

I would want to know if there exist such inequality and maybe a proof of the same.

Comment: Are you familiar with the inequality rank$(A + B)$ $\leq$ rank $A$ + rank B?

Comment: yes I have seen it before and have access to its proof

Comment: Consider the metric $d(X,Y)=\operatorname{rank}(X-Y)$. Your inequality says that $d(A,-B)\ge|d(A,0)-d(0,-B)|$. It is basically the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$rank(A+B)$ of two $p \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490686/rankab-of-two-p-times-n-matrices-a-and-b) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3138414/305862)

Comment: yes they do, I should delete this question then

Comment: Please delete the question @WGuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let us show that rank $A$ $-$ rank $B$ $\leq$ rank($A + B$). We have
$$\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} [(A+B)+(-B)] \leq \operatorname{rank}(A+B) + \operatorname{rank}(-B),$$
by the inequality in my comment above.